# how to filter data with xslt when all nodes are shown as attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am totally new to xsl. I am trying to filter data in this xml.

```
<SectorWeightings Currency="xxx">
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="A B||16.324500000000" Date="8/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="C||16.744400000000" Date="7/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="C S||10.177400000000" Date="8/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="C S||8.8950000000000" Date="7/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="E||12.841600000000" Date="8/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="E||13.551700000000" Date="7/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="Fi S||14.157900000000" Date="8/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="Fi S||15.221200000000" Date="7/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="H Care||12.508900000000" Date="7/31/2011" />
      <SectorWeightingsEntry Type="Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)" Value="H Care||13.198200000000" Date="8/31/2011" />
 </SectorWeightings>
```

Here is the code that I use to filter data

```
 <xsl:for-each select="FundPricePerf/Group[@Name=nds']/SubGroup[@Name='S']/Fund[@FundCode='xx']/SectorWeightings">
        <tr> 
         <td>     <xsl:value-of select="SectorWeightingsEntry[@Type='Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)']/@Value"/>   </td> 
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

above code will filler only the first row that is A B||16.324500000000.

How to print whole list?

Updated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>


<html>
<body>
<h2> zzzzzzzzz  </h2>




    <table style="width:50%;font-size:12px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">


    <tr style="width:50%; text-align:left;background-color:E6F1F9;">  

    <th>    xxxxx   </th> 
    <th>    yyyyy     </th>      
    </tr> 



    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="FundPricePerf/Group[@Name='xxxxx']/SubGroup[@Name='S']/Fund[@FundCode='vv']/SectorWeightings/SectorWeightingsEntry[@Type='Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)']"/>


<xsl:template match="SectorWeightingsEntry">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>


    </table>

</body>

</html>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main part of your XSLT needs to go in its own template, and the template for the `SectorWeightingsEntry`s needs to be separate from that, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2> zzzzzzzzz  </h2>

        <table style="width:50%;font-size:12px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr style="width:50%; text-align:left;background-color:E6F1F9;">
            <th>    xxxxx   </th>
            <th>    yyyyy     </th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:apply-templates
            select="FundPricePerf/Group[@Name='xxxxx']/SubGroup[@Name='S']
                    /Fund[@FundCode='vv']/SectorWeightings
                    /SectorWeightingsEntry[@Type='Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)']">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-after('||', @Value)" data-type="number"
                      order="descending" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SectorWeightingsEntry">
   <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 5">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-after(@Value, '||'), '#.#')"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when I tried your code it prints data without properly filtered

Comment: Which property?  In your example XML, every `SectorWeightingsEntry` has the type "Sector Name||Sector Weight (%)", so that last filter would have no effect in that case.

Comment: @MenukaDevinda The different parts of the XSLT need to be separated out into different templates.  I've added a more complete XSLT above, based on your example.

Comment: thanks and one question how can we substring on the result? I mean If I get a result like this  `C D||16.324500000000` how can I take out 16.3245 and round it to 16.3? Can we do this with xslt?

Comment: If I want to sort the list according to the number. How to do that?

Comment: Updated my answer. Do you want to sort from low to high or from high to low?

Comment: I want to filter first 5 values

Comment: The 5 highest values, or the 5 lowest values?

Comment: final question, how can I get the average of the 5 highest values?

Comment: @MenukaDevinda Could you open a new question with the current XSLT answer and ask about how to get the average? I don't think it's ideal to compound too many questions into a single thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606819/how-to-get-the-average-in-xml-data-using-xsl#comment20395079_14606819